How to upload a profile photo with MSGRAPH-SDK-PHP v2?
I've a young intern who need to implements msgraphv2 with PHP over a custom app we have.
Everything gone right with basics informations like services, phones, etc. We can read and write on our tenant, but the problem is with profile picture.
Is there anyone who know how to create a ProfilePhoto object, needed by the setPhoto method of user object?
$tokenRequestContext = new ClientCredentialContext(
    'MS_TENANT_ID',
    'MS_CLIENT_ID',
    'MS_CLIENT_SECRET',
);
$appClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext);
$appClient->users()->byUserId($userId)->setPhoto([myPic])->wait();

That's the [myPic] part we missed.
We also tried to get the current profile pic (with success), and modify content, but it also failed.
$myPic = $appClient->users()->byUserId($userId)->photo()->content()->get()->wait();
if (null == $myPic) {
    return null;
}

$binary = $myPic->getContents(); // Success
$appClient->users()->byUserId($userId)->photo()->content()->put($binary)->wait(); // Failed with Argument #1 ($body) must be of type Psr\\Http\\Message\\StreamInterface, string given


"failed" -- what exactly did you get? Please quote the error message you get, so people can (hint!!) search for it online. Also, use a debugger to step through the code and find out where and why it e.g. throws an exception. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

I'd already put the error message in comments for the second exemple, but for the first one, we didn't try to execute, because we looking for a way to create a ProfilePhoto object. And i have already make the tour and how to ask, i thought I followed the instructions...

And of course we have crawled the web like a fly, but the doc is very succinct, even non-existent...

Ah, I see. I have to scroll the code to the right in order to find the error message. I assume that $binary is the bytewise content of the picture. However, for the API, you need to provide a StreamInterface. There is an according StreamFactoryInterface (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-17/) which helps you create these. There are multiple implementations available, chances are that you installed one indirectly (e.g. via your app framework) that you only need to find in your vendor/ dir.

Many thanks @Ulrich, that was the good practice. I add the final code below! Have a nice day!

Many thanks to @Ulrich Eckhardt, problem is solved.
$tokenRequestContext = new ClientCredentialContext(
    'MS_TENANT_ID',
    'MS_CLIENT_ID',
    'MS_CLIENT_SECRET',
);
$appClient = new GraphServiceClient($tokenRequestContext);
$streamInt = GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::streamFor($binary);
$appClient->users()->byUserId($userId)->photo()->content()->put($streamInt)->wait();

With $binary the binary content of the photo, and $userId the MS Azure ID.
